# Notation of expected value, variance, and covariance

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, expected-value

In different lectures, books, and papers, I have seen many ways of denoting an expected value. Among them $E(\cdot)$, $E\{\cdot\}$, $E[\cdot]$, $\mathbb{E}(\cdot)$, $\mathbb{E}\{\cdot\}$, and $\langle \cdot \rangle$.

I understand that some are more common in specific fields, like $\langle \cdot \rangle$ in physics, and that a reason for some specific notations like $\mathbb{E}\{\cdot\}$ in some electrical engineering lectures might be to distinguish the expected value from energy. That aside, what is the "correct" way of writing an expected value? Is there a good reason brackets other than $(\cdot)$ should be used or the E should be `\mathbb{}`?

In a similar vein, how should variance and covariance be denoted? I've seen the same different type of brackets as above and also capitalized $\text{Var}(\cdot), \text{Cov}(\cdot)$ and lower case $\text{var}(\cdot), \text{cov}(\cdot)$. Again, is there a good reason to capitalize this as opposed to most other operators or to use curly or square brackets?

Comment: "Correct" way?  Unlike some areas of study, mathematics does not have an official body that rules on correct notations.  You may use whatever notations you like, as long as you explain what they are beforehand.  Any of your notations for expectation should be fine in math writing (except $\langle\;\cdot\;\rangle$, use that only in physics).

Comment: I get that I can basically define whatever notation I want. But usually, some characteristics are associated with specific notations, like using `\mathbb{}` for sets. So I'm wondering if there is a good reason to use one notation over the others? E.g. $\mathbb{E}$ does not seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: A reason not to use $R$ for the real numbers (as was common 50 years ago during my education) is to be able to use $R$ for an ordinary variable.  Same with $E$ for expectation. Next, do we somehow need to reclaim $e$ and $i$ for ordinary use?